# How to position events in calendar to be displayed at the correct time frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making a calendar/scheduler in ReactJS and was wondering the following. When I add an event to the calendar, I choose a time frame for instance 8:45 - 10:30. How would I position that event (it could be a button or link w/e) to appear in that specific time frame on the calendar?

Comment: That depends on how the HTML of your calendar is structured. We don't know anything about that, you didn't show any code or markup.

Comment: P.S. It's quite complicated to create a good calendar UI of your own. Why not use a ready-made, free solution such as https://fullcalendar.io/ or similar? It already handles many things including the problem you're asking about. It also has a React integration ready-made.